# Compiler error, when taking link to class as method argument

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand friendly classes in C++.
I made two classes: Lada ( Car ), and Mechanic.
Lada is friendly class to Mechanic, so Mechanic can view and change Lada's private variables.
Where you're itializing Lada, it takes one argument, bool isBroken ( no need to explain ).
And Mechanic class has method, that repairs Lada ( changes isBroken to false ).
I don't know why, but it shows an error:
>

```
C:\C++\FriendlyClassesTests>c++ Lada.cpp Lada.h Mechanic.cpp Mechanic.h main.cpp -std=c++20
In file included from Lada.h:3:
Mechanic.h:11:25: error: 'Lada' has not been declared
   11 |         void RepairLada(Lada& lada);
      |                         ^~~~
Mechanic.cpp:9:1: error: no declaration matches 'int Mechanic::RepairLada(Lada&)'
    9 | Mechanic::RepairLada(Lada& lada) {
      | ^~~~~~~~
Mechanic.h:11:14: note: candidate is: 'void Mechanic::RepairLada(Lada*)'
   11 |         void RepairLada(Lada& lada);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~
Mechanic.h:6:7: note: 'class Mechanic' defined here
    6 | class Mechanic
      |       ^~~~~~~~
In file included from Lada.h:3,
                 from main.cpp:2:
Mechanic.h:11:25: error: 'Lada' has not been declared
   11 |         void RepairLada(Lada& lada);
      |                         ^~~~
```

I included "Lada.h" file in both Mechanic.cpp and Mechanic.h files.

Mechanic.h file:

```
#ifndef MECHANIC_H
#define MECHANIC_H
#include "Lada.h"


class Mechanic
{
    public:
        Mechanic();

        void RepairLada(Lada& lada);

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // MECHANIC_H
```

Mechanic.cpp file:

```
#include "Mechanic.h"
#include "Lada.h"

Mechanic::Mechanic()
{
    // Constructor!
}

Mechanic::RepairLada(Lada& lada) {
    lada.isBroken = false;
}
```

Lada.h file:
https://pastebin.com/7mBd5H0A

Lada.cpp file:
https://pastebin.com/fj4PqazW

Sorry, for any mistakes in my english, i'm Ukrainian.
Hope for your help.

Comment: Can you show `Lada.h`, or rather a [mcve]?

Comment: @Kevin here is Lada.h: https://pastebin.com/7mBd5H0A

Comment: edit your question to include the code

Answer (score 1):

The error here is that you are including `Mechanic` in `Lada` and `Lada` in `Mechanic`, this leads to an infinite loop as the compiler does not know which one should be included first.

You can use `forward declarations` to declare `Mechanic` in `Lada` without having to include it:

```cpp
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#define SOMECLASS_H

class Mechanic; // Use this instead of #include
class Lada {
public:
    // ...
};

#endif
```

Comment: Nope. There is no infinite loop here thanks to `#ifndef`s. However there is an error in that Lada.h includes Mechanic.h instead of simply announcing the `Mechanic` class to make a friendship declaration.